Solving integral equation numerically
I tried to solve a integral equation numerically, but I failed. The equation is:$\epsilon(\beta)=r\cosh{\beta}+\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\varphi(\beta-\beta')\ln(1+e^{-\epsilon(\beta')})d\beta'$ were $\varphi(\beta)=\frac{-2\sqrt(3)\sinh(2\beta)}{\sinh(3\beta)}$
My strategy is to solve starting from $\epsilon_0=r\cosh(\beta)$ and $\epsilon_{n+1}=r\cosh{\beta}+\int\varphi(\beta-\beta')\ln(1+e^{-\epsilon_n(\beta')})d\beta'$
My first code was:
(*Kernel*)

phi[theta_] := Module[{value}, value = (-Sqrt[3]*2)*Sinh[2 theta]/Sinh[3 theta];
  If[Sinh[3 theta] == 0, Return[Infinity], Return[value]]
  ]

(*Initial value*)
e0[theta_] := r*Cosh[theta] /. r -> 0.1

epsilon[theta_] := Module[{epsPrev, epsNew, tol, maxIter, iter},
  epsPrev = e0[theta];
  Print[epsPrev];
  tol = 10^-14;
  maxIter = 100;
  iter = 0;
  
  While[iter < maxIter,
   epsNew[theta] = 
      e0[theta] + 
       NIntegrate[
        phi[theta - thetaPrime]*
         Log[1 + Exp[-epsPrev[thetaPrime]]], {thetaPrime, 0.1, 10}];
    
    (*If[!NumericQ[epsNew],Print[
    "Non-numeric value encountered at iteration ",iter];Break[];];*)
    
    If[Max[Abs[epsNew[theta] - epsPrev[theta]]] < tol, 
     Break[]];(*Convergence*)
   
   epsPrev = epsNew;
   iter++;
   ];
  epsNew
  ]

(*Plot epsilon*)
Plot[epsilon[theta], {theta, 0.1, 10}]

But it doesn't work. Please help me. It's the first time I use Mathematica

Welcome to Mathematica SE. Your code has a syntax error. Mathematica does not allow you to reuse theta in expressions like this: f[theta_] := Module[{}, g[theta_] := 1;], so you must change epsNew[theta_] := e0[theta] + .... Do you need a new function at that point in your code? I suggest that you use Print to help debug your code. For example, add Print[epsPrev]; after epsPrev = e0[theta];. Is the printed value what you expect to see? This result causes a problem because epsPrev is a numeric value, and  epsPrev[theta] doesn't work as you might expect.

It is not clear what kind of integral equation do you try to solve. Is it Fredholm equation or Volterra equation?

Please confirm the integration range {thetaPrime, 0.1, 10}

Thank you @creidhne. I changed as you suggested in while loopepsNew[theta] = e0[theta] + .... I used Print[epsPrev]  and prints many values: the second is not a numerical value but is 0.1Cosh[theta]. I don't know why only one. Moreover, I do not know why it prints many values even though the Print[epsPrev] command is outside the while loop. I update the code above

@AlexTrounev actually I don't know: the equation is from Thermodynamic Bethe Ansatz for Yang-Lee system: "Nuclear Physics B342 (1990) 695—720
North-Holland" eq (3.11).

@UlrichNeumann the integration range above it's just a test range. The actual range is -inf, +inf.

@AlessandroCortassa Ok, now we see that this is Fredholm equation.

@AlessandroCortassa Is there still interest in solving this integral equation? If yes, perhaps you could show solution plot from the paper?

Thank you very much @UlrichNeumann and Alex Trounev for your valuable answers! Now I try to understand them in depth, but in the meantime, I will point out to Ulrich that he finds some plot in the paper I wrote above, although unfortunately there is no graph of $\epsilon(\beta)$.

@AlessandroCortassa It looks like the original equation should be $-r \cosh \beta+\varepsilon +\phi*L=0$, were convolution defined with $\beta'/2\pi$. Compare to paper in your equation there are 2 typos with sign and $1/2\pi$ before integral.

Start with NestList (alterntive FixedPoint) to solve your problem
inf = 10; (* integration range -inf,...,inf *)
\[Beta]i = Subdivide[-inf, inf, 20];  (* grid *) 
epsi = NestList[
  Function[fa, 
   Block[{int }, 
    int[\[Beta]_?NumericQ] := 
     Block[{\[Beta]t}, 
      NIntegrate[-((4 Sqrt[3] Cosh[\[Beta] - \[Beta]t])/(
         1 + 2 Cosh[\[Beta] - \[Beta]t]^2 + 
          2 Sinh[\[Beta] - \[Beta]t]^2))*
        Log[1 + Exp[-fa[ \[Beta]t]]], {\[Beta]t, -inf, inf}, 
       Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
         "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]];
    Interpolation[
     Table[{\[Beta] , 
       e0[ \[Beta]] + int[\[Beta] ] }, {\[Beta], \[Beta]i}]]]], e0, 
  10]  

NestList evaluates some iterations, which unfortuantely don't converge. Here a plot of the two last iterations(blue)  and their difference(red).
Plot[Evaluate[ {epsi[[-1]][\[Beta]], epsi[[-2]][\[Beta]], 
   epsi[[  -1]][\[Beta]] - 
    epsi[[-2]][\[Beta]]}], {\[Beta] , \[Beta]i[[1]], \[Beta]i[[-1]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All , PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Dashed, Blue}, Red}]



Thank you very much @UlrichNeumann! Do you have any hypothesis as to why in the paper it is stated that the solution seems to converge fairly quickly, whereas here it has obtained a divergent result?

@AlessandroCortassa Sorry no idea. Sometimes it helps to consider the differentiated integral equation, but therefor you need to know eps[0] or eps[Infinity]

We use original equation (3.11) from the paper
$-r \cosh \beta+\epsilon +\phi*L=0$, where $\phi=-\frac{2\sqrt{3}\sinh (2\beta)]}{\sinh (3\beta)}$, $L=\log(1+e^{-\epsilon})$, and convolution integral is defined as follows
$\phi *L=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(\beta-\beta')L(\beta')\beta'/(2\pi)$.
This problem can be solved with using FDM. First, we suppose that $\epsilon=r \cosh \beta+P(\beta)$. To compute $P$ we use code
(*Kernel*)phi[x_] := (-Sqrt[3]*2)*Sinh[2 x]/Sinh[3 x];

L = 20; h = .1; X = Range[-L, L, .1]; np = Length[X]; P = 
 Array[pp, np];
r = .1; eq = 
 Table[P[[i]] + 
   h/(2 Pi)  Sum[(phi[X[[i]] - X[[j]] + $MachineEpsilon]*
         Log[1 + Exp[-r  Cosh[X[[j]]] - P[[j]]]] + 
        phi[X[[i]] - X[[j + 1]] + $MachineEpsilon]*
         Log[1 + Exp[-r  Cosh[X[[j + 1]]] - P[[j + 1]]]])/2, {j, 
      np - 1}], {i, np}];

sol = FindRoot[Table[eq[[i]] == 0, {i, np}], 
    Table[{P[[i]], .1}, {i, np}]] // Quiet;

Visualization
{ListLinePlot[Transpose[{X, P /. sol}], PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Beta]", "P"}], 
 ListLinePlot[Transpose[{X, r  Cosh[X] + P /. sol}], PlotRange -> All,
   ScalingFunctions -> "Log", AxesLabel -> {"\[Beta]", "\[Epsilon]"}]}


Using P as initial data for Ulrich code we have
ini = Interpolation[Transpose[{X, P /. sol}]];
r = .1; inf = 20; (*integration range-inf,...,inf*)
\[Beta]i = Subdivide[-inf, inf, 400];  (*grid*)
epsi = NestList[
  Function[fa, 
   Block[{int}, 
    int[\[Beta]_?NumericQ] := 
     Block[{\[Beta]t}, -1/(2  Pi) NIntegrate[
        phi[\[Beta] - \[Beta]t + $MachineEpsilon]*
         Log[1 + Exp[-r Cosh[\[Beta]t] - 
             fa[\[Beta]t]]], {\[Beta]t, -inf, inf}, 
        Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
          "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]];
    Interpolation[
     Table[{\[Beta], int[\[Beta]]}, {\[Beta], \[Beta]i}]]]], ini[#] &,
   7]

Visualization
Plot[Evaluate@Table[epsi[[i]][x], {i, 1, 7}], {x, -20, 20}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]


As we can see solution converges to the FDM solution.

Nice solution. I tried similar ansatz with NestList but it didn't conevrge!

@UlrichNeumann Thank you. We know that this solution is very tricky since it diverges at $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$.

As an addition to your nice answer see my approach using  Gaussian quadrature.

@UlrichNeumann Thank you very much (+1).

I still don't understand the reason, why you took starting value r in the Findroot command, because result depends significantly on this starting value

@UlrichNeumann Actually, as we know from the theory, we should add some boundary conditions for this equation to find unique solution.

If you try FindRoot[Table[eq[[i]] == 0, {i, np}],      Table[{P[[i]], .0}, {i, np}]] // Quiet; you see a different solution

@UlrichNeumann Yes, you are right. This numerical solution is not unique, since boundary conditions are not given. In general, we should add some bc, for example, in a form of  $\epsilon(0)=\epsilon_0$.

I am still pondering the solution of the transformed integral equation. P[beta]==Integrate[phi[...] Log[1+Exp[-(Cosh[beta']+P[beta']]],...] . First part of the integrand is negative, second part is always positive I think. This means that P[beta] must always be negative in contrast to our results.  Where is my error in reasoning? Thanks!

@UlrichNeumann Actually a theory of this equation is very complicated - see  https://www.sci-hub.ru/10.1016/0550-3213(90)90333-9?ysclid=m21zz1osmb218690898

@UlrichNeumann Please see update to my code with equation taken from the paper :)

Your update with modified integralequation looks very promising!  Thanks

Also the Gauss variant agrees with your new results!

NestList variant converges too with initial conditions 0!

modified(corrected integral equation, see answer Alex Trounev)
In addition to the nice answer given by @AlexTrounev here a fast approach which uses Gaussian quadrature and interpolation:
phi =Function[{theta},Evaluate@TrigExpand[(-Sqrt[3]*2)*Sinh[2 theta]/Sinh[3 theta]]];

Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"] 

r = 1/10; 
e0 = Function[theta, r*Cosh[theta]];
inf = 20;
\[Beta]i = Subdivide[-inf, inf, 70 ]; (* discretization*)


xwGauss =Flatten[Map[GaussianQuadratureWeights[3(*5*), #[[1]], #[[2]]] & ,Partition[\[Beta]i, 2, 1]], 1] ;

\[Epsilon]i = Table[eps[i], {i, 1, Length[\[Beta]i] }]; (* unknown parameters*)

intGauss[ epsi_List ] := Block[{\[Beta]t, ipeps   }, 
ipeps = Interpolation[Transpose[{\[Beta]i, epsi }] ];
Total@Map[#[[2]] 1/(2Pi)phi[\[Beta]i - #[[1]]]*Log[1 + Exp[-(r Cosh[#[[1]]] + ipeps[ #[[1]]])]] & , xwGauss]    ]   

soli = FindRoot[\[Epsilon]i + intGauss[\[Epsilon]i],Table[{\[Epsilon]i[[i]], .1}, {i, Length[\[Epsilon]i]}]] // Quiet;

show result
{ListPlot[Transpose[{\[Beta]i, Values[soli]}], PlotRange -> All,Joined -> True],
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{\[Beta]i, Values[soli] + r Cosh[\[Beta]i]}],PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]}


Result agrees well with Alex's modified answer and only need's a rougher discretization.

Please, see update to my code and solution with your method as well.
